# Flutter , Rendering List box builder horizontally with Grid box giving Render Layout Error

Tags: flutter

In the below screen i want to show a horizontal ListView builder Widget with scroll of unlimited text boxes . Whenever i do the same it results in "RenderBox was not laid out:"
How we can achieve the same in this case .

```
        class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _ProductsOverviewScreenState createState() => _ProductsOverviewScreenState();
        }
        
        class _ProductsOverviewScreenState extends State<ProductsOverviewScreen> {
          final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
          var _isInit = true;
          var _isLoading = false;
        
          @override
          void didChangeDependencies() {
            if (_isInit) {
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = true;
              });
              Provider.of<Products>(context).fetchAndSetProducts("").then((_) {
                setState(() {
                  _isLoading = false;
                });
              });
            }
            _isInit = false;
            super.didChangeDependencies();
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0,
                title:
                    Text('View All', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge),
              
              ),
              drawer: AppDrawer(),
              body: _isLoading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : ProductsGrid(),
            );
          }
        }
```

// ProductsGrid is returns a GridView.Builder and below is what i am trying to run

```
            body: _isLoading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : Column(
                      children: [
                        ListView.builder(
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            // code for the list builder 
                          },
                        ),
                        ProductsGrid(),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set ListView and ProductsGrid inside a Column, try to wrap them inside an Expandend Widget or set a property on the ListView called `shrinkWrap: true`.

Example:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // code for the list builder 
        },
      ),
    ),
    ProductGrid(),
  ],
)
```

or

```
Column(
  children: [
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // code for the list builder 
      },
    ),
    ProductsGrid(),
  ],
),
```

Comment: It is giving "Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#3bc73 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
Performing hot reload...   "